# Integration of Hybris with SAP-ERP

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have some questions related to the integration between Hybris and SAP, and I would appreciate if someone could throw some light on these doubts I have.

Ref: https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8c6b1537866910148811df9d8ce1e582.html

The above link explains how SAP can be integrated with Hybris so that the Order Management can be handled by SAP. It also suggests that SAP can be leveraged for pricing and tax calculation which means that Hybris can be bypassed.

Similarly there can be integrations with external PIM (Product Information Management), CRM and other business processes.

Hybris, as I understand manages the product, orders, taxes, etc... If in a real life scenario, all this information and business processes are managed from outside Hybris, then what is the purpose of having Hybris? Is it only a front-end app then?

Other references that made me ask this question:

- https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/99fd9ee7e7654886a95744c34da1dfb6.html
- https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/8c7087fe86691014b45ada177449dcdb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hybris is a platform with a set of modules that provide different features for your business.

In real life you will use some of hybris' modules **and** also external tools such as SAP ERP for example.

Hybris offer integration with a lot a partners in order to meet customer needs. When a company wants to build an e-commerce platform using hybris it might also want to reuse existing elements of the company (CRM, PIM, etc...). Sometimes, the modules from hybris don't fit customers needs and they prefer to use other tools for a specific area (could be cheaper to implement). That's why it's great to have the possibility to integrate hybris with other softwares.

You can also start a project without using any module of hybris but the accelerator. Then you'll have the opportunity to migrate your existing module into hybris to build a powerfull multi-channel solution.

It's up to you to use hybris ootb modules and/or external tools, it depends what you really need!

Comment: Well that's exactly what I am trying to ask. So if in an integrated environment, all the information displayed in Hybris is coming from external systems (SAP, CRM, PIM etc.) then what is the purpose of having Hybris. Can i not use just one of the so many WCMS softwares that are available in the market, intgerate that with ERP and then provide an omnichannel digital experience? Wouldn't that be cheaper as well? Why should anyone bear the huge license cost of Hybris if a relatively less priced WCMS software can do the job?

Comment: It also makes me think: is Hybris front-end not meant for organizations that are already hugely using SAP?

Comment: As I said, even if hybris is just used for the frontend, it offers the possibility to migrate to hybris integrated functionalities. So it might be chosen for long term strategies. Of course if a company just plan to use hybris as a front and never use the other modules then yes, we may ask why invest so much money in an hybris licence (however in such case you might just buy the module you need but I'm not sure). To answer your second question, no, hybris front-end is not meant for company already using SAP. It's a "common" JEE webapp using spring, you can even use other CMS (AEM for ex.)

Comment: Thanks Alain for this clarity. And as you mentioned that big time SAP clients need not necessarily go for Hybris solution. Then what was the purpose for Hybris getting acquired by SAP? The process automation that Hybris provides, would certainly not be more sophisticated than an SAP system.

Comment: SAP acquired hybris because they didn't have such tool (front-end) so it expand their potential customers pool. The 2 concurrents, IBM and Oracle offer better solutions than SAP used to. I guess that's why they bought hybris.

Comment: For front-end, they would only need a WCMS software. Why would they need all the business processes modules from Hybris, when they already have them all?

Comment: It's not ony a matter of front-end. There is also the global architecture which is not something that can be done by a WCMS. hybris offers a great JEE/Spring architecture upon which developers can implement almost whatever the customer wants. There are also backoffices that are directly connect to hybris, ready to use, and adapted to hybris and e-commerce. I'm not sure you'll find all of that with existing SAP app, and if you do the integration and your global infrastrucutre will be more complex to maintain. Last reason is existing customers, you can't force them to migrate to a full SAP suite